# Kudu Azure App Zip Deploy via Powershell - Transfer files to wwwroot

Tags: azure, powershell, kudu

I am using the Kudu Azure Zip Deploy API from powershell.

How can I ensure that the contents of the deployed zip folder are extracted within wwwroot with wwwroot being the containing folder?

**Current:**

(here my zip folder is the container within wwwroot)

/site/wwwroot/MYZIPFOLDERNAME/CONTENTS

**Expected:**

(I want the contents of the zip folder to be added directly to wwwroot and outside of the zip folder name)

/site/wwwroot/CONTENTS

I have followed the documentation like below and have a powershell script like below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip

```
#PowerShell
$username = "<deployment_user>"
$password = "<deployment_password>"
$filePath = "<zip_file_path>"
$apiUrl = "https://<app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password)))
$userAgent = "powershell/1.0"

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -UserAgent $userAgent -Method POST -InFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

When the script is finished, the zipped file is uploaded to my site, however the content is packaged within the folder and nested under the wwwroot directory.

If I use the ZipDeployUI and drag the folder, it unzips into the wwwroot/ directory without the folder name as expected.

Comment: why would the script unzip it for you? is that specified in the documentation?

Comment: @lloyd, the documentation says the default path is wwwroot but is unclear about there being a folder.  Using the ZipDeployUI puts the zip folder directly into wwwroot without the nested directory, whereas powershell adds the nested directory, so curious why the difference?  Is there a good way to copy over the files ie a post deploy trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the offical document [`Deploy your app to Azure App Service with a ZIP or WAR file`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip) to run the PowerShell script in the subsection [`With PowerShell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip#with-powershell), it's OK and works fine.

Your issue was caused by the file structure of your zip file. I will show you the difference.

There are two xml files in my directory `D:\projects\xml` on local. I packaged them into a zip file `xml.zip` using two different way: with a container `xml`, without any container, as the figures below via `7-zip`.

Fig 1. a container `xml` in the zip file `xml.zip`

[image]

Fig 1.1. the container `xml` contains two xml files

[image]

Fig 2. no container in the zip file `xml.zip`

[image]

Then I run the same PowerShell script with different zip file which has different file structure, I got the different result in the `ZipDeployUI` of my WebApp, as the figures below.

Fig 3.  Run the PowerShell script with the zip file which has a container `xml`, the `xml` container be decompressed under `wwwroot`

[image]

Fig 3.1. the two xml files within the container `xml` under the path `wwwroot/xml`

[image]

Fig 4. Run the PowerShell script with the zip file which has no container, the two xml files be decompressed directly under `wwwroot`

[image]

So please package these files directly to a zip file, not package their parent directory, if you were using some tools like `7-zip`. Or in the PowerShell command line, please first `cd` move to the directory which contains these files you want to package, then to run `Compress-Archive -Path * -DestinationPath <file-name>.zip` to get a zip file, as [`Create a project Zip file`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip#create-a-project-zip-file) said.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much @PeterPan !